# IE9 nested table fill height of parent td

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to nest tables and I want the nested tables to have heights equal to the heights of their containers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Col 1</th>
                        <th>Col 2</th>
                        <th>Col 3</th>
                        <th>Col 4</th>
                        <th>Col 5</th>
                        <th>Col 6</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>a</td>
                        <td>b</td>
                        <td>c</td>
                        <td class="has-nested-table">
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>d</td>
                                        <td>e</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td>f</td>
                        <td>g</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>h</td>
                        <td>i</td>
                        <td>j with some other letters because he has been so lonely lately</td>
                        <td class="has-nested-table">
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>k</td>
                                        <td>l</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td>m</td>
                        <td>n</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>o</td>
                        <td>p</td>
                        <td>q</td>
                        <td class="has-nested-table">
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>r</td>
                                        <td>s</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>t</td>
                                        <td>u</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>v</td>
                                        <td>w</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td>x</td>
                        <td>y</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here's the CSS
    *
    {
        margin:0;
        outline:0;
        padding:0
    }

```
html, body
{
    font:normal 11px/1.4 Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    height:100%
}

.wrapper
{
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0 10px;
    width:940px
}

table
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    height:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%
}

    thead
    {
        background:#595959;
        border:1px solid #595959
    }

    tbody, tr
    {
        height:100%
    }

        th
        {
            color:#f5f5f5
        }

        th, td
        {
            padding:5px
        }

        td
        {
            border:1px solid #ccc;
            text-align:center;
            vertical-align:top
        }

        td.has-nested-table
        {
            padding:0
        }

            td table
            {
                height:100%
            }

            td td
            {
                border-bottom:0;
                border-left:0;
                border-top:0;
                vertical-align:top
            }

            td td:last-child
            {
                border:0
            }
```

The nested tables expand in firefox and chrome but not in IE9. Help!

Answer (score 0):

Add this css and then try

```
td.has-nested-table table{
   height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are assigning the border to

```
td td {
```

and as the text takes in connecting column take more space as in

```
<td>j with some other letters because .... </td>
```

the nested table will not expand as it has only one row.

So to fix this, in addition to the @Harshit answer you need to add

```
td td { border: 0px; }
```

Check the http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/8UxbS/

working fine on IE and looks much better if border are not important in nested table, but if border are required then you need to add rowspan and stuff but that will not be full proof

Comment: unfortunately, i need those borders

Comment: can't think of anything, you can make table-layout: auto but that will stretch the long column.

Comment: Changing tbody, tr { height:100% } to height: auto works fine for firefox now with borders also but still the IE is not working, you can try this http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/8UxbS/1/